# Calculator that recognizes days, weeks, and months within a timeframe

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I'm trying to make a calculator that will allow me to input a start date and return date for a rental item that then accesses a chart on another sheet with the daily, weekly, and monthly rental cost for that specific item and returns a total price.

For example, rental of Item 1 from Feb 1 – March 10 is 1 month, 1 week, 2 days….the math should be $2848.75(1 month) + $1192.5(1 week) + ($265x2)(2 days) = $4577.25.

I already have the cells for the start and stop date, and a cell that computes the number of applicable days that the item was rented for. How can I make a cell that automatically gathers the correct total price? ($4577.25 in example)

Second sheet with pricing information:
[image: Second sheet with pricing information]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "***...the number of applicable days***" this might not be a relevant number since it depends on how which months it was to know by what to pool it to a month's price.

Comment: I'm using that cell for the information of the user of the calculator. I don't necessarily need to implement it into the formula for the total cost.

Comment: Did the Feb is 28, 29 days? Why is 1 week, 2 days? If 1 Month is Feb1-Feb 28or 29, then the March 1- March 10, this should 1Week, 3 days... Could you provide more information?

Comment: I believe your assumption about "month" are incorrect. At least in the US, rental companies I have dealt with define a "month" as 30 days.  So your rental rate would be based on 1 month, 1 week and 0 days. You can do some lookups to get the total cost. If that is not the case, kindly supply the algorithm for which **your** rental company is computing a **month** as a month can have 28, 29, 30, or 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the prettiest, but using these formulas should do the job

[image]